# CSS transition rule inherently overridden when creating an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

So I'm creating an element in javascript and I assign certain style attributes to it and add a class to the element. In my stylesheet I have a few rules for said class - however the transition rules that I have in the CSS file are not being applied to the element. Is there a reason the newly created element isn't getting these rules? In safari I see them crossed out in pink.
Heres my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tester</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elm = document.createElement("div");
    elm.classList.add("testcls");
    elm.style.width = "100%";
    elm.style.height = "20em";
    elm.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
    setTimeout(function() {
        elm.style.height = "10em";
    },1000);
};
```

style.css:

```
.testcls {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: there is invalid property value for transition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the units of the transition duration in your CSS rules:

```
.testcls {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUtYL/)